# Difference between "Serial Send" and "To Instrument" blocks

Tags: matlab, serial-port, simulink

The Instrument Control Toolbox in MATLAB/Simulink contains two blocks that can send data to a device on a serial port:

- [`Serial Send`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/instrument/serialsend.html): Send binary data over serial port
- [`To Instrument`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/instrument/toinstrument.html): Send simulation data to instrument

It looks like the `To Instrument` block is more general-purpose than `Serial Send`. `To Instrument` allows you to select the underlying interface, with one option being "Serial".

What is the difference between `To Instrument` (when configured with Interface=Serial) and `Serial Send`?  Is there any reason to prefer either one for sending, say, 4 bytes of numeric data to the device?  Are there any other situations where only one of them would work?

Answer (score 3):

One difference:

The "To Instrument" and "Query Instrument" blocks are older blocks and were hardcoded to only be used for ports COM1-COM4. For a device that's on a different serial port, please try the "Serial Send" and "Serial Receive" blocks to achieve the same functionality. The block parameters dialog for these blocks should auto-populate the list of available COM ports to communicate with so that you can select the proper port for your device.